# meteor app failling for no appearant reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

when I run my app I get the following error message

```
Errors prevented startup:

While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
client/templates/posts/post_item.js:59:3: Unexpected token (59:3)

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
Started MongoDB.
```

the mentioned part of my code is the following (the last line to be exact)

```
Template.postItem.events({
  'click .upvotable': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('upvote', this._id);
  },
  'click .disable': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('unupvote', this._id);
  }
});//here is the problem
```

can someone please help me get what's wrong

the entire file is there if needed:

```
Template.registerHelper("isGreaterThanZero", function(array) {
  check(array, Array)
    if(array.length>0){
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }})

Template.postItem.onCreated(function (){
  Meteor.subscribe("tags")
  Meteor.subscribe('singlePost', this._id)

})

Template.postItem.helpers({
  ownPost: function() {
    return this.userId == Meteor.userId();
  },


    tags: function() {
    var arr = [];
    if(this.tags){
      if (this.tags[0]){
        for(var i =0;i<this.tags.length;i++){
            if (Tags.find({body: this.tags[i]}).fetch()[0]) { 
              if(!(Tags.find({body: this.tags[i]}).fetch()[0] in arr)){
                arr.push(Tags.find({body: this.tags[i]}).fetch()[0])}}}                
        return arr} else {
          return arr
        }
  } else {
    return arr
  }};

Template.postItem.events({
  'click .upvotable': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('upvote', this._id);
  },
  'click .disable': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('unupvote', this._id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is that also the last line of the file? Maybe post the entire template, HTML and JS.

Comment: @zim yes it's the last line of the file

Comment: @zim I am not sure if the rest of file will be relevant

Comment: Probably is. You may have a redundant or missing bracket somewhere.

Comment: Sometimes an error on the last line indicates a problem further up.

Comment: @zim I added the entire file

Comment: @zim excuse my bad habbits of programming

Comment: At a minimum, the helpers is missing a closing paren. There may be other mismatches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the helpers(), you are shy 1 closing paren and you're missing 1 closing brace in the tags() helper.